# Installing android apk file in emulator without command prompt

Tags: android, sdk, apk

I want to Install apk file in an Emulator without using any Command prompt.

Can we install it without using command?

Can some one guide me in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the eclipse open file explorer view , Import your apk file to memory, then in the emulator install it

Comment: @MortezaSoleimani Can you please Explain me properly? i am unable to do that.

Comment: Do you use eclipse IDE ?

Comment: Choosing a best answer will help many others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Goto terminal.
2. Move to `adt/sdk/platform-tools` folder.
3. Type in the following command:

   ```
   ./adb install your_application.apk
   ```

*You can also use Airdroid. It is a good app with more useful features.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Genymotion](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/) emulator. In that, you can install APK by drag and drop the APK on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

From the command prompt/shell/terminal: Browse to the platform-tools directory
Then type the following command.

```
adb install [.apk path]
```

Example:

```
adb install C:\Users\Name\Desktop\test.apk
```